# HTML5 LocalStorage - how to use it with hyperlinks?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm hoping to use HTML5 Local Storage on my web page data so it persists beyond a page refresh.

Here is my code:

```
<h3 data-target="#colours_filters">Colour</h3>
<ul id="colours_filters">
    <li class="filter-option"><a href="#" data-tax="colours" data-filter=".tag-colours-black-2">Black</a></li>
    <li class="filter-option"><a href="#" data-tax="colours" data-filter=".tag-colours-blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

So if I click 'Blue' and/or 'Black', it will store this in `LocalStorage`?

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/k5pnj4a4/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.filters a').on('click', function() {

        var data_filter = $(this).closest("a").data('filter');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            localStorage.setItem(data_filter,true);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(data_filter,false);
        }

    });

   $('.filters a').each(function(){
        var data_filter = $(this).closest("a").data('filter');
        var checked = localStorage.getItem(data_filter);
        if(checked){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try first to give unique id to your elements

```
<h3 data-target="#colours_filters">Colour</h3>
<ul id="colours_filters">
    <li class="filter-option"><a href="#" id='unique_1' data-tax="colours" data-filter=".tag-colours-black-2">Black</a></li>
    <li class="filter-option"><a href="#" id='unique_2' data-tax="colours" data-filter=".tag-colours-blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.filter-option a').on('click', function() {

        var isActived = $(this).hasClass('active') == false; 
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        localStorage.setItem(id,isActived);

        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    });

    $('.filter-option a').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        var hasActiveClass = localStorage.getItem("active");

        if(hasActiveClass != undefined){
            $(this).addClas('active');
        }
    });

});
```

[fiddlejs](http://jsfiddle.net/blashadow/sd9zmoe5/)

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response :-) I tried using this code... I clicked a colour, refreshed the page, but unfortunately it didn't keep the clicked colour 'active' as I had hoped. Any ideas?

Comment: try to give id to each element and save the state and id of elements, then when you reload the page collect all ids,find on the dom and give the active class if is the case.

Comment: Thanks for this @BlaShadow - I'm quite new to jQuery, can you possibly update your answer to show me how I would best do this? I would greatly appreciate any assistance with this :-)

Comment: I've tried the new code, but unfortunately I'm still not getting any further forward :-( I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function test.html:44(anonymous function) test.html:44e.extend.each jquery.min.js:2e.fn.e.each jquery.min.js:2(anonymous function) test.html:38o jquery.min.js:2p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2c.addEventListener.B`

Comment: This is good advice, except I very much disagree with the view that *you should give unique IDs to your elements*. Not all elements need to be uniquely identified, and if somebody ever hopes to extend your element type with a twist, IDs will make that difficult.

Comment: @Katana314 in my example what you would use for a unique identifier (identifier for use it on localstorage)?

Comment: @BlaShadow That partially depends on the intent of the stored value - I actually somewhat expected all colors to be stored as an array under a single storage id. Remember that you now have "unique-2" as a localStorage value set globally to the entire domain.

Comment: That's right with this I will have " 'unique-2' as a localStorage value set globally to the entire domain".